How to get opening, Purchase , issue, closing stock with date filter
I have a one table. in the table purchase Qty updated as Positive Sign And Sale Quantity Updated With Negative Sign



Date
Batch
Item
Quantity




1-08-2024
1
Pen
200


1-08-2024
1
Pen
-10


2-08-2024
1
pen
-20


01-09-2024
1
pen
-30


04-09-2024
1
pen
-50



Now When I Pass  Date = 01-08-2024 and To date= 04-09-2024 I want to output like below



Date
Batch
Item
Opening Stock
Purchase
Issued
Balance




1-08-2024
1
Pen
0
200
0
200


1-08-2024
1
Pen
200
0
-10
190


2-08-2024
1
pen
190
0
-20
170


01-09-2024
1
pen
170
0
-30
150


04-09-2024
1
pen
150
0
-50
100



and Also  I Pass Date = 01-09-2024 and To date= 04-09-2024 I want to output like below



Date
Batch
Item
Opening Stock
Purchase
Issued
Balance




01-09-2024
1
pen
170
0
-30
150


04-09-2024
1
pen
150
0
-50
100




Please do not delete and repost questions.

How do you know the opening stock of 01-09-2024 as 170 without also including the records 1-08-2024 thru 2-08-2024?  Are you providing 2 date ranges at the same time to the query?

Isn't this just a cumulative SUM? There are 100's of examples of these; why didn't they work?

@BartMcEndree one would have to materialize the whole sum and then take the dates one's interested in

consider balance as opening stock for next row

Why does 01-09-2024 have a balance of 150? Where do the extra 10 come from? (200-10-20-30 = 200-60 =140)

sorry not 150, 140 is correct

This is just a (couple of) cumulative SUM, the key thing is you need to calculate this first and then return the rows you want. One method of doing that is with a CTE to get the SUMs and then SELECT from that:
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20240901',
        @EndDate date = '20240904';

WITH Balances AS(
    SELECT YT.Date,
           YT.Batch,
           YT.Item,
           YT.Quantity,
           ISNULL(SUM(YT.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.Batch, YT.Item ORDER BY YT.Date
                                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS OpeningBalance,
           CASE WHEN Quantity > 0 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END AS Purchase,
           CASE WHEN Quantity < 0 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END AS Issued,
           SUM(YT.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.Batch, YT.Item ORDER BY YT.Date
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Balance
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT)
SELECT B.Date,
       B.Batch,
       B.Item,
       B.Quantity,
       B.OpeningBalance,
       B.Purchase,
       B.Issued,
       B.Balance
FROM Balances B
WHERE B.Date >= @StartDate
  AND B.Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate);


Note that the balances for 2024-09-01 and 2024-09-04 differ to your expected results; I get 140 and 90 respectively.
As discussed in the comments, rather than 2 windows, you would likely be better off using subtraction in the outer scope for the prior balance:
WITH Balances AS(
    SELECT YT.Date,
           YT.Batch,
           YT.Item,
           YT.Quantity,
           CASE WHEN Quantity > 0 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END AS Purchase,
           CASE WHEN Quantity < 0 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END AS Issued,
           SUM(YT.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY YT.Batch, YT.Item ORDER BY YT.Date
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Balance
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT)
SELECT B.Date,
       B.Batch,
       B.Item,
       B.Quantity,
       B.Balance - B.Quantity AS OpeningBalance,
       B.Purchase,
       B.Issued,
       B.Balance
FROM Balances B
WHERE B.Date >= @StartDate
  AND B.Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate);


Why perform the same sum twice? Would it be more efficient to simply use the lag of Balance as OpeningBalance in the 2nd query?

You would have to use a second CTE for that, @BartMcEndree . You're welcome to compare the plans though: db<>fiddle

YOu could, however, just minus the Quantity from the Balance, I suppose, @BartMcEndree : db<>fiddle

Interesting solution. Thank you.

Btw, i read somewhere that it's good to keep the window function calls together in sql server, so they can reuse the same "window" instead of doing it separately. And yeah, you should decrease the current amount from the aggregated to avoid different windows.

how can i add grand total for above

That's a new question, @ramanareddy . Though there are plenty of examples of how to SUM out there. Don't edit your question to change the question after you've received answer(s).

yes but how to add grand total?

Like I mentioned in your new question, you appear to already have that, it's just the last row for that product. But that's something you should address in that other question.
